# Show Upvoted Questions

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Often when going through the app I will just browse one of the list of questions. Along the way I will up/down vote the questions and would use this on the main site to keep track of where I am when back tracking.

These votes don't show up in the list view for the app, though. It makes going through many questions frustrating.
Possibly just display color/direction change.

Example list.

[image: List example]

Comment: Not sure what you ask. We can't see which questions we upvoted in any question list.

Comment: Yes. I would like it to be so. Show the actions you took on a question/answer in the list view.

Comment: Well, I agree with Patrick, voting is a wrong way to keep track on questions. That's what we have favorites for.

Comment: As I said on the conversation on the answer I'm not tracking with upvotes, just actions. If you think favorites are the right answer then I'd like to  have them show up on the list.

Comment: Upvoting this question:) Would love to have this feature too.

Answer (score 2):

> I will up/down vote the questions and would use this on the main site to keep track of where I am when back tracking

Voting is not a way of backtracking. If your sole purpose of voting is to find your interesting posts, it is wrong. You should vote on the post, not on your desire to come back at any point.

On the site, there is the ability to view your actions, filtered on voting. ([See yours here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=all)) It is not possible (yet) to see that in the app. You just have to manually go through the question list.

Instead of porting the votes page to the app, I prefer to be able to mark posts as favorite and see the favorite questions list on the app.

Comment: I don't vote on each question as I view it. Only on this that help me, I want to know and can't figure out, or on those that I think are well written. It's often enough when I browse to be at least one per page which helps track. Maybe a better solution would be show read questions?

Comment: Well, I wanted to make sure you are doing this the right way. Why not use favorites? It is made for this purpose.

Comment: These aren't favorite questions though. I could use that as a work around, but this is a feature request. I feel this would help with browser flow to see actions